# Get the owner and their mileage with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables using MySql; `Owners` and `Cars`, where an owner has a birthdate and the cars have mileage records. The tables look kinda like this:

```
Owners:
+-------+--------------+
| Field | Type         |
+-------+--------------+
| id    | varchar(10)  |
| birth | datetime     |
| name  | varchar(100) |
+-------+--------------+

Cars:
+--------------+-------------+
| Field        | Type        |
+--------------+-------------+
| plate        | varchar(6)  |
| mileage      | int(11)     |
| owner*       | varchar(10) | //fk references Owners
+--------------+-------------+
```

I want to get to get the youngest owner and their mileage selected using SQL. I've managed to get the car of the owner being the youngest, but I don't know how I could like JOIN the tables and create a table containg the Owner-attributes AND the mileage-attribute from their car.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cars 
WHERE owner = (SELECT id 
               FROM Owners 
               WHERE birth = (SELECT MAX(birth) FROM Owners));
```

Which I said returns the car e.g.

```
+--------+---------+------------+
| plate  | mileage | owner      |
+--------+---------+------------+
| KFO405 |    8109 | 9912218527 |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

But I want it like this:

```
+------------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------+
| id         | birth               | name                  | milage     |
+------------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------+
| 9912218527 | 1999-12-21 00:00:00 | Marva Rocha           |       8109 |
+------------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------+
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Each owner can have a single car?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes, they only have one car

Comment: The one who downvoted, I'm not usually bothered, but I just can't see how this question bothered anyone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: Why is that some kind of Communist country people can only have a car? :) Anyway if the relationship is 1:1 then why you have a separated table for `Cars`? just add it as additional fields for `Owners.`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Not a communist country, just a small example-solution hehe. Owners won't be in BCNF if I do

Comment: I don't even know what time I was born

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza ?? The cars can only have one owner.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, every car can have a single owner, Unless again you are in a Communist / Socialist  Country where the properties is for everyone but the reality is just the one in the power get all the benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the youngest owner and mileage

```
  SELECT A.ID, A.BIRTH, A.NAME, B.MILAGE
  FROM Owners A
      INNER JOIN Cars B
      ON A.ID=B.owner
  ORDER BY A.birth ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically join the tables first and then define the criteria (Birth):

```
SELECT Owners.name,
       Owners.birth,
       Cars.plate,
       Cars.milage
FROM Owners
JOIN Cars ON Cars.owner = Owners.id
WHERE Owners.birth =
        (SELECT MAX(birth)
         FROM Owners)
```

Comment: Misspelled "Owners" to "Ownders", otherwise a useful solution as well

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the spelling.